# semantic ui remote validation

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI along with ASP.NET MVC. I have performed client-side validation in my registration form as described in the documentation http://semantic-ui.com/modules/form.html Now i want to validate an email in order to be unique. So i have to make an ajax request to the server (this is something i know how to do). But how can i add such a rule in Semantic UI and display a corresponding error message?

Answer (score 0):

After a little search [at the docs](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/form.html) I found the behavior `add errors`. It works like

```
$('.your.ui.form').form('add errors', ['Your error string 1', 'Maybe another one?']);
```

However, this will only change the text in the error messages. If the error message is not displayed at that time, you will probably want to show it. Add the class 'error' to the form:

```
$('.your.ui.form').addClass('error');
```

And of course you can chain these two methods like

```
$('.ui.form')
  .form('add errors', ['oh my error'])
  .addClass('error');
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v38m3vax/1/)